# Mac/PC: How to change the developer of an Apple Disk Image?

Tags: macos, dmg, code-signing, gatekeeper

I am trying to use a GD-0912-U Intuos Graphics Tablet in OS X El Capitan‎ at a public hackerspace. They will let me install any programs on the iMac, barring that Gatekeeper believes it is from a trusted developer.

I have been able to get this tablet working in Windows 7 by installing older drivers that were found online. This tablet is obviously not going to work with current Intuos drivers.

I have managed to find [drivers](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6630975?start=0&tstart=0) that will likely work, but I cannot install them unless the OS believes that the app is from a trusted developer. New drivers downloaded from the Wacom website install perfectly, and show that Wacom is the official developer. It seems that the old drivers were created before Gatekeeper existed; therefore, they do not have the proper developer information.

Is there a way to alter developer information on an Apple Disk Image?

Could I take information from recent Intuos drivers and copy it into the .dmg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The developer certificate signs the application and any modification of the seal will make the validation fail.

Basically any trivial cut and paste won't work. You would need to:

- sign up as a developer and sign your package
- get permission from Apple to sign kernel extensions if that is the nature of the driver
- work with the maintainers of the lab to find and install drivers for your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** install the drivers on your Mac (but I dont't know if they'll work properly)
All you have to do is to stop temporary Gatekeeper:

- Open the dlmg package
- Press the ctrl key on your keyboard, and click once on the pkg file, you'll see a local menu.
- Click "Open", you'll see the Gatekeeper alert, but with another button: "Open"
- Click on open, and the installation will begin!